# Have any of you tried out SFX Machine Pro?

Tags: software, vst, plug-ins, review

Audio-MIDI.com is having one of their "No-Brainer" deals right now, and it's for this SFX Machine Pro plugin, for 87% off. It's only $20, but I'm between gigs at the moment and don't want to blow $20 on something dumb. It bills itself as an amazing sound design tool, but the only demos I can find online are it being used on terrible third-rate rap songs.

So, have any of you tried it? And if you have, have you used it in a sound design capacity? I'd love to hear your feedback.

http://www.shareit.com/product.html?cart=1&productid=300077342

Answer (score 1):

It's a great plugin and the $20 deal is a steal

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I bought it and i would say it's OKAY....but nothing mind blowing in there in my opinion....however it does have alot of stuff in it...i just found that I can already do most of the things it offers with other plugs. if you have 20 to blow check out the animoog iOs app...its awesome. Cheers! -jason www.soundmorph.com

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome to download a free demo from
http://sfxmachine.com/downloads.html .

Earl Vickers

The Sound Guy, Inc.

http://sfxmachine.com